# Keeping the sidebar the same height as the content

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, height, element

I'm making a typical wordpress theme, based on [twentysixteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/).

I'm trying to keep the `.sidebar` div as long as the `.content-area` div. The pure CSS solutions, like flexbox won't work for me, for a number of reasons.

So... here's my jQuery function:

```
    window.sidebarSize = function(){ 
    ( function( $ ) {
        var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
        var contentArea = $('.content-area');
        var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

        //only if sidebar is next to contentarea
        if (parseInt(viewportWidth) >= 910){
                //if sidebar is longer than the content
                if(parseInt(sidebar.outerHeight(true)) > parseInt(contentArea.outerHeight(true))){
                    sidebar.css('height',''); //reset sidebar height to its minimum
                // else, sidebar is shorter than content
                } else {
                    sidebar.css('height',contentArea.outerHeight(true)); //make its height the same

                }
        }
    } )( jQuery );

};
```

This is called like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {    
//a bunch of event handlers here because I'm not sure which of these work
$(window).on('window.onload window.onresize load resize', function() {
    window.sidebarSize();
});
```

The above works, although sometimes there's a hiccup and it won't apply until I refresh the page.

But now I have another problem.

Occasionally, the size of the content will change dynamically (I'm using the [Collapse-O-matic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-collapse-o-matic/) plugin to collapse galleries and FAQs), and I'd like the sidebar to follow suit.

I've tried a bunch of solutions but all failed. At the moment I'm using [this script](https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize), but it doesn't always work, as I have described [here](https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize/issues/46).

Especially with the FAQ page, where the content height can change in multiple ways several times in a row, the scripts will just go bananas and the sidebar length will start to look incoherent.

Any suggestion as to where these scripts can be improved will be really appreciated. I am a bit of a javascript noob.

Comment: in modern browsers can all be done using css flexbox with no script needed

Comment: I thought as much but I couldn't really make it work in flexbox. I played around with the properties but the divs kept overlapping each other -- the sidebar width is 27%, please if you can post some css on how to apply this in flexbox. Also, are you sure it would work dynamically?

Comment: actually scratch the above, I find another guide online that seems a little clearer, maybe I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

You have dynamical content on the front-end, meaning some of the content is hidden and then reveals when clicked (or other event control).  That dynamic content will affect the height of its parent container.

### How can you adjust the container heights to be the same when dynamic content is revealed?

You will need to *listen for the event that changes the content*.  In other words, when the control that opens up that content is clicked, you want to add a listener to that event.

Why? Then when the content expands down changing the height, your height setter script can readjust the CSS for both columns.

### Implementation

Using the HTML and CSS markup from the twentysixteen theme, here is an example of dynamic content.  This [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hellofromtonya/m3mj5nf5/) adds a FAQ content revealer.

Here is the script that automatically adjusts the column heights for the content area and sidebar.

```
/*!
* This script adjusts the column heights
*/
(function($, window, document){
    "use strict";

    var $contentArea, 
        $sidebar;

        var init = function() {
        $contentArea = $('#primary');
        $sidebar = $('#secondary');
        $('.faq-question').on("click", setHeights);
        setHeights();
    }

    var setHeights = function() {
        clearHeights();
        var height = getHeight();

        $sidebar.css('height', height);
        $contentArea.css('height', height + 40);
    }

    function clearHeights() {
        $sidebar.css('height', '');
        $contentArea.css('height', '');
    }

    function getHeight() {
        var contentHeight = $contentArea.outerHeight(true),
            sidebarHeight = $sidebar.outerHeight(true);

       return contentHeight > sidebarHeight
           ? contentHeight
           : sidebarHeight;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        init();
    });

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

When you click on the question, the answer is revealed.  In doing so, the content container's height changes.  The script is listening for that click event.  When clicked, it retriggers the `setHeights()` function.

### How to add the click listener?

For the plugin you are using, you'll need to see what it is targeting for opening and closing the content.  Then you can add your own event to retrigger setting the heights.

Comment: I tried implementing this, I am sure it can work 100%, but I find there is a problem with it: if I bind the resizing on when I click, **the sidebar will become longer when I click to collapse**, and **shorter when I click to expand**. This happens simply because _at the moment of clicking the height is still unchanged!_ That's why I was using the script I linked to above, which listens to 'scroll'... It seemed a good idea but still doesn't work quite right. Is there a way to just listen to the div changing height?

Comment: @nico Notice that when you click to expand the content in the JSFiddle example, the script recalculates the _new_ height and then applies that height to both the content and sidebar containers.  It grows with the content.  Then when you click to close it, it repeats the resizing.  It's dynamic.

Comment: uhm, it might be but it doesn't work for me :) -- I have to keep my other function (as posted above) because I need this adjustments to be also done on load. Maybe the two scripts interact negatively, I should understand where and how; also, there are actually more css changes that happen in the sidebar when it changes in height (such as certain widgets being positioned absolutely or relatively)... but I don't know where I can place these instructions in your script?

Comment: @nico Yes, you will want to replace your height setting code with the above or merge/adapt it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to script a solution for this. You don't need CSS flexbox or floats either.

All you need to do:

1. give the `body` the `background-color` that you want your `.sidebar` to have;
2. add a `position: absolute` to the `.sidebar`;
3. give the `.content-area` a `min-height` of `100vh`, its own `background-color` and a margin which corresponds to your intended width of `.sidebar`

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
margin: 0;
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.content-area {
display: block;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);;
margin-right: 29%;
min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
display: block;
position:absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 27%;
padding: 12px;
}

h1, h2 {
margin: 0;
padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<main class="content-area">
<h1>I am the main content area</h1>
</main>

<aside class="sidebar">
<h2>I am the sidebar</h2>
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</aside>
```

**N.B.** The implicit assumption in the layout above is that the `.sidebar` will never be taller than the `.content-area`, once the `.content-area` is taller than the height of the viewport.

Comment: This is neat but cannot work on my layout, where I have separate divs on a transparent canvas. Imagine each "article" visually separated, where "content-area" is purely transparent. Furthermore all the divs in question use border-images. I cannot just do this with background color.

Comment: Bear with me, because I'm 98% certain that whatever layout you need to produce, it will be possible with CSS alone. For instance, if you use a background gradient on body, that will enable content-area to have no background-color at all. Is there any way you can add a screenshot to your question of the layout you want to produce?